# Upload image file to blob column using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two fields in my edit page 1.domainName 2.logo
When I click on submit button, selected picture and domain name should update the table 
I tried the below, but its not updating the database.

```
<%= form_for(@company, :multipart => true) do |form| %> 
<table style="height: 400px; border: 5px; margin-left: 20px; ">
<tr>
        <td width="40%">
          <%= form.label :domain_name ,"Domain Name"%>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= form.text_field :domain_name %><%= form.submit "Add Domain" %>
        </td>
  </tr>
<tr>
         <td>
            <%= form.label :company_logo,"Company Logo" %>
         </td>
          <td>
              <%= form.file_field :company_logo %>
          </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

In controller
def update
    @company=Company.find_by_company_id(params[:id])
    if @company.update_attributes(params[:company]) then
      render :text=>"Company Details updated successfully"
    end
end
```

Comment: is there any reason to save image in blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is there any reason to save image in blob? you can use [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) gem to upload a file.

May be it's not updating blob because it requires raw data and it's may be tempfile
try this

```
company_logo_blob = params[:company][:company_logo].read #or params[:company][:company_logo].tempfile.read    

@company.update_attributes(:domain_name =>params[:company],:company_logo=>company_logo_blob)
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Almost I spent 4 hours on this. Thanks alot

Comment: As Image file takes more memory, I choose blob type. There is no other reason. Sorry for the late reply.